# How to select count of combination of values in one column which match single value of other column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data as below :

Table is : order_details (order_id int not null, prod_id int not null)

**Order_id Prod_id**
1                        1
1                        2
2                        3
3                4
4                    1
4                2
4                    7

I need to find the combinations of two or more products which are sold together in an order.
For this data this will be Product 1 and 2 as these are occurring twice for a single order.
I need the products which occur together for most orders and the count of orders for which they occur together.

I am using this query:

```
select distinct od1.prod_id,od2.prod_id from order_details od1 join order_details od2 on od1.order_id=od2.order_id  where od1.prod_id!= od2.prod_id limit 10;
```

This works for only combination of 2 products and does not give the count.

Can this be made better?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists t;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table t (Order_id int,Prod_id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.19 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into t values
    -> (1 ,             1),
    -> (1 ,             2),
    -> (2 ,             3),
    -> (3 ,             4),
    -> (4 ,             1),
    -> (4 ,             2),
    -> (4 ,             7),
    -> (5 ,             1),
    -> (5 ,             2),
    -> (6 ,             1),
    -> (6 ,             2),
    -> (6 ,             7),
    -> (7 ,             1),
    -> (7 ,             2),
    -> (7 ,             7),
    -> (8 ,   7),
    -> (8 ,  2)
    -> ;
Query OK, 17 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 17  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select s.prodmix,count(*) Obs
    -> from
    -> (
    -> select order_id,
    -> group_concat(prod_id order by prod_id asc) prodmix, count(*) as obs
    -> from t
    -> group by order_id
    -> having count(*) > 1
    -> ) s
    -> group by prodmix
    -> order by obs desc limit 2;
+---------+-----+
| prodmix | Obs |
+---------+-----+
| 1,2,7   |   3 |
| 1,2     |   2 |
+---------+-----+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I used : 
SELECT s.prodmix,
       count(s.prodmix) Obs
FROM
  (SELECT order_id,
          group_concat(prod_id
                       ORDER BY prod_id ASC) prodmix,
          count(*) AS obs
   FROM order_details
   GROUP BY order_id HAVING count(*)
 > 1) s
GROUP BY prodmix
ORDER BY obs DESC LIMIT 2;